# Opening port 53 for DNS

Tags: dns, firewall, ufw

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS and am attempting to set a DNS server up. The DNS server is running in a virtual machine and is working when I run dig/netstat against it. However it is unresolvable from my host OS. As indicated below.

```
host@host:/~ # netcat -zv 192.168.15.15 80
Connection to 192.168.15.15 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!

host@host:/~ # netcat -zv 192.168.15.15 53
netcat: connect to 192.168.15.15 port 53 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I have allowed it as an option in UFW

```
guest@guest:/~ # ufw allow 53
```

Although this did not work, I even tried disabling UFW altogether, this did not work either. 
Can anyone tell me how to open this port?

Comment: Is your VM NAT'ed or bridged?

Comment: I have 2 adapters on my VM, one is NAT(dhcp) and the other is a host only adapter (static 192.168.15.15).

Comment: By the way, the `necat` command is trying to use port 53 `TCP`, not `UDP`, which may be the problem.

Comment: True, but my dig command is also failing, which I suppose is more to the point. So when I do something like h@h~/:# dig example.com @192.168.15.15     I get a 'connection timed out: no servers could be reached' error

Comment: dig always runs into a timeout if it can't reach a DNS that actually answers.

Comment: This is not really about opening the port but getting a DNS server up and running throgh a VM to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure something is actually listening on that port (`netstat -tlnp | grep 53`), if your firewall would have blocked you, you'd usually just run in a timeout since it would drop the packages without answering.

You actually get an answer which is connection refused.

Which

1. tells you there is nothing there or
2. your DNS doesn't accept the requests,

while the first probably being the case.